# XCode: Invalid host string 'localhost'

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, hosts

I'm getting this error: "Invalid host string: 'localhost'" every time I try to compile code on my laptop. My desktop, however, works just fine.

Both the laptop and the desktop have the exact same hosts file in etc/hosts, that is:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

I've searched so much around the internet and all of them have the same answer: Your hosts file is named incorrectly. But it's not.

It's named hosts. I have made two copies, hosts.txt and just hosts and neither of them work. This leads me to think it's something in XCode's preferences that's looking for hosts somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have a webserver running on your desktop that isn't running on your macbook?

Answer (score 0):

Can you mention your OS ?

Mostly MAC OS X lion giving this error because Apple remove web sharing from 10.8.x

If your OS is 10.8.x then use this link.
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57481978-263/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/

After implementing this link just restart your system

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

I was running against the same problem on a run-time of xcode debug. Are you running gas mask? If so, I was simply under the remote file rather than the local in my settings.